# Updating object on controller from UI router's resolve method, called by $state.go()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, watch

I use UI router's `resolve` object to add a dependency (a promise) to a controller. On initial page load, this gets resolved as intended and the object in the controller is populated with the data from the dependency. I use this object in the view to output a `ng-repeat` directive.

In another state, I have a function that adds to the model (the same that is getting resolved on the previous state). Once added, I transition the state back to the previous state with `$state.go()`.

As the `resolve`'s method fetches the model and injects the dependency into the previous controller, I expect that the `ng-repeat` output should include the newly added item. But it doesn't. Only when refreshing does the view get updated.

From `console.log`ing in the `resolve` method, I can see that the method is being called and that the data has been fetched.

I placed a `$watch` on the dependency to update the controller's object with the new values, but that watch doesn't get called. Why does the `$watch` not see the change in the dependency, when it has clearly changed?

**Route**

```
angular.module('app')
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider

    .state('tab', {
        url: "/tab",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
    })

    .state('tab.queries', {
        url: '/queries',
        views: {
            'tab-queries': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/tab-queries.html',
                controller: 'QueriesCtrl as ctrl'
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            allTemplates: function(Templates) {
                return Templates.all().then(function(templates) {
                    console.log(templates); // This outputs with the correct data every time the state is entered
                    return templates;
                });
            }
        }
    })

    .state('tab.guide', {...}); // controller: GuideCtrl as ctrl
});
```

**QueriesCtrl**

```
function queriesCtrl($scope, allTemplates) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.queries = allTemplates;
    $scope.$watch('allTemplates', function() {
        // Called on first load, not on subsequent state changes
        console.log('templates changed');
        vm.queries = allTemplates;
    });
}
```

**GuideCtrl**

```
function myCtrl($state) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.goToQueries = function() {
        /* -> Code saving to the model here <- */
        $state.go('tab.queries');
    }
}
```

**View (tab.queries)**

```
<div ng-repeat="query in ctrl.queries">
...
</div>
```

Comment: I have got a such problem. It seemed to work. But it does not work now. It is related with caching. I can not resolve it. Have you found a solution? Look caching http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/